# Applying patch files using perl?

Tags: perl, scripting, patch

This should be simple,

Is there a way to apply .patch files using perl?

I am aware I can use `system` I am looking for a module or something. I have looked on [search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org) but I guess I am not typing the right search to get what I want if it exists.

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of [Text::Patch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aPatch).

You just need to read/write the source/patch files as this module is targeting in-memory text, not simple files.